# Using multer, CSRF and express-validator together in nodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer, express-validator, csrf-token

In my node.js app I have an `ejs` form which has some text input fields that `express-validator` should validate, an **image** file which uses **`multer`**, and an hidden input that contains a `CSRF` token. (I have this token in all the other forms in my app too)

The problem is, that the `CSRF` middleware is **global** and runs for each request **before** the middlewares in my routes files, and the `multer` middleware runs in one of this routes files.

I know that `multer` should be placed **before** the `CSRF` middleware, but in my case I have to put `multer` inside the routes - because I want it to run **after** `express-validator` finished validating the text inputs.

**Why do I want `multer` to run before `express-validator` and can't make it global?**

Because if I make multer global, then in case I have a **valid** file in my form, even if the text inputs are **invalid** - **the file will still uploaded by multer**, because multer has ran before the express-validator started runnig, and that's the big problem.

So to solve this, I placed the `multer` middleware inside the routes and after the validator, but now there's the issue with the `csrf` that needs multer.

Here are parts of my code:

**multer middleware:**

```
const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, "images");
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, uuidv4() + "-" + file.originalname);
    },
  });
  
  const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if (file.mimetype === "image/jpeg" || file.mimetype === "image/jpg" || file.mimetype === "image/png") {
      cb(null, true);
    } else {
      cb(null, false);
    }
  };

 
module.exports = multer({ dest: "images", storage: fileStorage, fileFilter:fileFilter}).single("image");
```

**The route file that contains multer and express-validator:**

```
const { productValidators } = require('../middleware/validators')//The express validator middlewares
const multer = require('../middleware/multer')

router.post("/add-product",isAuth,productValidators,multer,adminController.postAddProduct);
    
router.post("/edit-product",isAuth, productValidators,multer, adminController.postEditProduct);
```

So in short, my problem is that I need multer to stop uploading the image if other validation failed. But the only way to do so is by adding `multer` middleware after the `express-validator` instead of making it a global middleware, which causes the `csrf` problem.

Is there an alternative to this?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

The middleware using express receive methods the function `req:Request, res:Response, next: NextFunction`.

Primary Validated middleware, if not allowed:

```js
return res.status(401).json({
  message: 'Error identification keys'
})
```